# How do you switch on a string in XQuery?

Tags: xml, switch-statement, xquery, case

I have an external variable coming in as a string and I would like to do a switch/case on it. How do I do that in xquery?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Starting with XQuery 1.1, use switch:

http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-11/#id-switch

```xquery
switch ($animal) 
   case "Cow" return "Moo"
   case "Cat" return "Meow"
   case "Duck" return "Quack"
   default return "What's that odd noise?"
```

Answer (score 4):

Just use a series of if expressions:

```xquery
if ($room eq "bathroom") then "loo"
else if ($room eq "kitchen")  then "scullery"
else "just a room"
```

Using a typeswitch is hiding what you are really doing.

Which of these methods is most efficient will depend on the XQuery processor you are using.  In an ideal world it should only be a matter of taste, as it should be down to the optimizer to select the appropriate method, but if performance is important it is worth benchmarking both versions.  I would be very surprised if a processor optimized the node construction out of your example, and didn't optimize my example to a specialized switch.

Comment: Sometimes it is nice and elegant to hide what you really do if you dont forget that you are doing it ...

Comment: I down voted this because the question is trying to find the syntax of switch/case not if/else.

Comment: @Sixty4Bit - When I answered the question the behaviour of switch was not finalized, which was why I posted my second answer in February!

Answer (score 3):

XQuery doesn't have a function for switching on anything other than elements.

The first thing you do is convert your string to an element.

```xquery
let $str := "kitchen"
let $room := element {$str} {}
```

Then just use typeswitch to do a normal switch:

```xquery
return typeswitch($room)
  case element(bathroom) return "loo"
  case element(kitchen) return "scullery"
  default return "just a room"
```

***Please note, this may be a MarkLogic only solution.***

Comment: This solution will (should) work in any xquery processor, but is not as clear as the straightforward nested if solution.

Comment: I just hate nested if's. I like the XQuery 1.1 example so I marked it as the answer.

Answer (score 3):

If your processor supports XQuery 1.1, then you can simply do:

```xquery
switch ($room) 
  case "bathroom" return "loo"
  case "kitchen" return "scullery"
  default return "just a room"
```

Answer (score 1):

For Saxon, you can use something like this:

```saxon
declare function a:fn($i) {
typeswitch ($i)
 case element(a:elemen1, xs:untyped) return 'a' 
 case element(a:elemen2, xs:untyped) return 'b' 
 default return "error;"
};
```

https://rrusin.blogspot.com/2010/01/xquery4j-in-action.html